# How does the problem of classification of Riemann surfaces extend beyond the uniformization theorem?

Tags: riemann-surfaces

If the uniformization theorem gives a 'first classification' of Riemann surfaces into hyperbolic, parabolic, and elliptic surfaces, then what would a 'second classification' look like? If it makes any sense to consider such a thing...

I know that there are (up to conformal equivalence) three simply connected surfaces, and that any riemann surface may be realised as the quotient space of the covering surface by the fundamental group. Within these classes, are there sub-classes, so to speak?

Comment: Have you read "Riemann surfaces" by Ahlfors and Sario?

Comment: I have not, and I hadn't actually heard of it. A quick browse of the contents shows me that chapter IV is 'Classification Theory'. Seems like a good place to start. Thanks

Comment: Right: It will probably give you more than you asked for.